# On closed, symplectically embedded surfaces of ambient compact symplectic manifolds, how does one avoid pulling back a 2-form to an exact 2-form?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms, smooth-manifolds

Obviously, if one pulls back an exact (with respect to the de Rham d) differential form by any map, then one obtains an exact form on the submanifold.

But if one starts out with a form that isn't exact, how can we guarantee that we don't pull it back to an exact form on the embedded submanifold?

Since I'm working with closed embedded surfaces, Stokes's theorem provides an easy criterion to determine if the pullback is exact or not.  But this doesn't provide me much information about the original form on the ambient manifold.

I would like to be able to explicitly construct a 2-form on the ambient submanifold that I know - even without testing it with Stokes's theorem - will not pull back to exact form.  Is there a special characteristic class of the normal bundle of the submanifold that I should use?  Will some theory about Poincare duals of submanifolds help me here?

Comment: Your question seems too vague to answer. What, precisely, are you pulling back?

Comment: Really, what I want to do is choose a member of the degree-2 de Rham cohomology of the ambient symplectic manifold according to the specifications: the member must be in the kernel of (n-2)-power of the Lefschetz map (associated to the symplectic structure) at the level of cohomology, and the member must not pull back to the zero class in the degree-2 cohomology of the symplectically embedded submanifold.

Comment: I am a priori assuming, of course, that said kernel is not zero.